# Show that if $(m,n) = 1$, then for any number $p$, we have $(p,mn) = (p,m)(p,n)$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show that if $(m,n) = 1$, then for any number $p$, we have $(p,mn) = (p,m)(p,n)$.

**Added Context:**

Any divisor of $p$ is a divisor of $(p,m)$ and $(p,n)$. Therefore, $(p,mn)\mid(p,m)(p,n)$.

How can we use the fact that $(m,n)=1$ to show that $(p,m)(p,n)\mid(p,mn)$?

Comment: Use the FTA and it's immediate.

Comment: what do you mean immediate?

Comment: Look at the factorization given by the FTA for each number.

Comment: Do you already know that $\, a(b,c) = (ab,ac)?\ \ $

Comment: Why do you call a number $p$ if it is not assumed to be prime? This is quite confusing.

Answer (score 2):

$\gcd (p,m)=px_1+my_1$ and $\gcd (p,n)=px_2+ny_2$ $\implies$ $\gcd (p,m)\gcd (p,n)=p(px_1x_2+nx_1y_2+mx_2y_1)+mn(y_1y_2)$. Thus we have $\gcd(p,mn)$ $|$ $\gcd (p,m)\gcd (p,n)$.

Similarly we get, $\gcd (p,mn)=px_3+mny_3$. Thus we have, $\text {lcm}$ $(\gcd (p,m),\gcd (p,n))$ $|$ $\gcd(p,mn)$.

Now notice that $\text {lcm}$ $(\gcd (p,m),\gcd (p,n))=\gcd (p,m)\gcd (p,n)$. Hence you are done.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a=(p,m)$ and $b=(p,n)$. To show that $ab=(p,mn)$ you have to show that:
(1) $ab$ divides $p$;
(2) $ab$ divides $mn$;
(3) $ab=pu+mnv$ for some integers $u$ and $v$.

(2) and (3) are straightforward and don't need the assumption $(m,n)=1$.

To prove (1), let $x$ and $y$ be integers such that $1=mx+ny$. Then
$$\frac p{ab}=\frac{p\cdot1}{ab}=\frac{p(mx+ny)}{ab}=\frac pb\cdot\frac ma\cdot x+\frac p a\cdot\frac n b\cdot y.$$
Since $\frac p a,\frac p b,\frac m a,\frac n b$ are integers, this shows that $\frac p{ab}$ is an integer, i.e., $p$ is divisible by $ab$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $ma+nb=1$.

Let $q=(p,m)$ and $r=(p,n)$. Then $q\mid(p,mn)$ and $r\mid(p,mn)$, and therefore,
$$
qr\left[\left(\frac mqa\right)\frac{(p,mn)}r+\left(\frac nrb\vphantom{\frac aq}\right)\frac{(p,mn)}q\right]=(p,mn)
$$

Thus, $(p,m)(p,n)\mid(p,mn)$.

Suppose $(p,m)=pa_1+mb_1$ and $(p,n)=pa_2+nb_2$, then
$$
(p,m)(p,n)=\left[(pa_1a_2+ma_2b_1+na_1b_2)\frac{p}{(p,mn)}+b_1b_2\frac{mn}{(p,mn)}\right](p,mn)
$$
Thus, $(p,mn)\mid(p,m)(p,n)$.

Therefore, $(p,mn)=(p,m)(p,n)$.